# Adding custom method to product collection

Tags: magento2, overrides, dependency-injection, extend

What is the best way to add some method to for example product collection?

1. I would like to add method which can be called on loaded collection (in fact it will be a filtering one for products that doesn't have any category assigned). The best will be situation if I want to use it I still inject Magento collection class, not mine - I guess it is possible with use of dependency injection.
2. I have `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` and also `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` - which one I should extend?

Comment: use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory

Comment: I eddited question - of course I am using factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should extend \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection and create a preference for your class in di.xml like this:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="Your\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" />
```

You would then inject \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory in order to use it.

Comment: But to all these thing to work properly my class should extend from `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`, I guess. Am I right?

And if I do it in module A will my changes be available in module B?

Comment: Yes, that's what you should do. The create method of \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory will then return the desired object across the application.

Answer (score 0):

Actually after some time  I think, in some conditions (doesn't happen for product `Collection`) there is another solution. If class is replaced in `Api` section of module by an `Interface` and it implements that interface it's possible to replace it custom module with `preference` on real class. Example of Api section in `module-catalog`:

`<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface" type="\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Repository" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionTypeInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductTierPriceManagementInterface" type="\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\TierPriceManagement" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\ScopedProductTierPriceManagementInterface" type="\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ScopedTierPriceManagement" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\TierPrice" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryProductLink" />`

The steps that should be proceeded:

- Make your own implementation of class you want to replace, adding
  your custom logic.
- In your module that is loaded later then original, declare `preference` on that `Interface` again, but argument `for` should be your implementation. It will work, but only in places of application, where you put in DI `Interface` instead of its implementation. Then you just replace called class with no harm.