# Magento 2 override the product collection(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection.php)

Tags: magento2, product, overrides, catalog, resource-model

We want to override the product collection model class(**Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection.php**)

We flow the below process to override the **addAttributeToSort** method but not working.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="MyModule\SortByQty\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" />
</config>
```

**Collection.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace MyModule\SortByQty\Model\ResourceModel\Product;


class Collection extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
{
    public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
    {
        if ($attribute == 'position') {
            if (isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {
                $this->getSelect()->order($this->_getAttributeFieldName($attribute) . ' ' . $dir);
                return $this;
            }
            if ($this->isEnabledFlat()) {
                $this->getSelect()->order("cat_index_position {$dir}");
            }
            // optimize if using cat index
            $filters = $this->_productLimitationFilters;
            if (isset($filters['category_id']) || isset($filters['visibility'])) {
              $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('_inventory_table'=>'cataloginventory_stock_item'),
            "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id ",
            array('qty')
        )->order(array('_inventory_table.qty DESC'));
            } else {
                $this->getSelect()->order('e.entity_id ' . $dir);
            }

            return $this;
        } elseif ($attribute == 'is_saleable') {
            $this->getSelect()->order("is_saleable " . $dir);
            return $this;
        }

        $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
        if ($attribute == 'price' && $storeId != 0) {
            $this->addPriceData();
            if ($this->_productLimitationFilters->isUsingPriceIndex()) {
                $this->getSelect()->order("price_index.min_price {$dir}");
                return $this;
            }
        }

        if ($this->isEnabledFlat()) {
            $column = $this->getEntity()->getAttributeSortColumn($attribute);

            if ($column) {
                $this->getSelect()->order("e.{$column} {$dir}");
            } elseif (isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {
                $this->getSelect()->order($this->_getAttributeFieldName($attribute) . ' ' . $dir);
            }

            return $this;
        } else {
            $attrInstance = $this->getEntity()->getAttribute($attribute);
            if ($attrInstance && $attrInstance->usesSource()) {
                $attrInstance->getSource()->addValueSortToCollection($this, $dir);
                return $this;
            }
        }

        return parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
    }
}
```

Please, can you help on above issue? any references and suggestion are highly appreciated.

Comment: Pls check here https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Magento2-rewrite-product-resource-collection-class-does-not/td-p/65131

Comment: Pls check here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169601/rewrite-magento-catalog-model-resourcemodel-product-collection-showing-error

Comment: @Abdul I have already tried the above shared link but not working for addAttributeToSort method.Please let me know if any other suggestion.

Comment: wich functionality you want to customize in product collection ex:sort ,filter etc

Comment: @BirjitsinhZala we want to override the addAttributeToSort method to sort by quantity I have already added the code inside the method.it's working on core file.But unable to override.

Comment: I also face this issue. Please give proper solution.

Comment: @PayalPatel Please use plugin https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento2-rewrite-product-resource-collection-class-does-not/td-p/65131  also  check if particular class is not replaced by API interface if so then replace that API interface by preference in you di.xml https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124606/adding-custom-method-to-product-collection?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

Kindly use plugin for this.

put below code in `Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
    <plugin name="product-collection-sorting" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Product\Collection" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Create `Namespace\Module\Plugin\Product\Collection.php` and pasted below code in your file:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin\Product;

class Collection
{

    public function afterAddAttributeToSort(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $subject, $result)
    {
         // do your stuff here
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you....!

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the block Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar

put below code in Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="cutom_productlimit" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
</type>
```

Create plugin file Namespace/Module/Plugin/Product/Toolbar.php

```
 <?php 
namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList;    
class Toolbar
{

   public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $CurrentDirection = $subject->getCurrentDirection()? $subject->getCurrentDirection(): 'DESC';
         // do your stuff here
        return $result;
    }
}
```